# Column Division

Tags: education

I'm new at Mathematica. I need to find all the reminders of a division between two integers - just like column division - and stop until I obtain a reminder equal to one of those already found. 
For istance: 37/22

In[17]:= Mod[37, 22]

Out[17]= 15

In[20]:= Mod[150, 22]

Out[20]= 18

In[21]:= Mod[180, 22]

Out[21]= 4

In[22]:= Mod[40, 22]

Out[22]= 18

then it stops.
I learnt how to use If and Do, but I guess it's not enough and there're better functions to perform this job. Thank you

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContinuedFraction.html ?

Comment: This will need a bit of cleaning. `FixedPointList[QuotientRemainder @@ # &, {773240, 68423}]'

Comment: This is better: `In[296]:= NestWhileList[
 QuotientRemainder @@ # &, {773240, 68423}, #[[1]] > 0 &]

Out[296]= {{773240, 68423}, {11, 20587}, {0, 11}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an auxiliary function that mimics what your division example, i.e. multiplies the dividend by 10 whenever it is smaller than the divisor, and returns only the remainder.

```
columnDivRem[a_, b_] /; a < b := QuotientRemainder[10 a, b][[2]]
columnDivRem[a_, b_] := QuotientRemainder[a, b][[2]]
```

Then the "main" function, without `If`'s or `Do`'s, that repeatedly applies this function to it's own results until one of the remainders is a duplicate, or a zero remainder is found.

```
columnDiv = Function[{div1, div2},
  NestWhileList[columnDivRem[#, div2] &, 
   div1, ({##} === DeleteDuplicates@{##} && FreeQ[{##}, 0]) &, 
  All, 1000]]

columnDiv[37, 22]
(* {37, 15, 18, 4, 18} *)
```

`NestWhileList`'s last parameter prevents the function from executing indefinitely, such as in @Daniel Lichtblau`s evil example, by limiting the number of executions to 1000:

```
columnDiv[773240, 68423]    
{773240,20587,601,6010,60100,53616,57199,<<987>>,67534,59533,47946,499,4990,49900,20039}
```

#### Fixed-point version, inspired by @Daniel Lichtblau

```
columnDivFixed = Function[{div1, div2}, 
  FixedPoint[Append[#, columnDivRem[Last@#, div2]] &, {div1}, 1000,
    SameTest -> (#1 === DeleteDuplicates@#2 || Last@#2 == 0 &)]];
```

Comment: Ack, I posted an improvement that's similar and then saw this. I'll upvote and maybe leave the comment also.

Comment: That OK! I suspect there is still room for a `FixedPoint` solution...

Comment: One variant is to use `Quiet` and drop the last four or so list elements. But it still isn't the same as the "shift by factor of 10 and redivide" regimen which I guess is what was wanted.